# Send CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST request with action parameter in MFC Smart Device Application

Tags: http, visual-c++, post, mfc, smart-device

How to send action string parameter using CHttpFile ??
Here is my code

```
CInternetSession session(_T("My Session"));
CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
try
{
CString strServerName = _T("192.168.1.39");

CString szHeaders = _T("Content-Type: text/plain");
//To Be Send    
**CString strFormData   _T("action=setCameraSetting&videoOverlay.useTimestamp=1&videoOverlay.useText=1&videoOverlay.displayString=12.12-77.32");**

INTERNET_PORT nPort = 1039;
DWORD dwRet;
CString strObject = _T("/cgi-bin/camera.cgi");
pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort, _T(""), _T(""));
pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, strObject);
pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);
pFile->SendRequest();
pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);
delete pFile;
delete pServer;
}
catch (CInternetException* pEx)
{}
session.Close();
```

I got Response code 200 for this..

Comment: 200 indicates success. What seems to be the problem, then?

Comment: Yaeh, In the above code i have not sent action string parameter (strFormData). I want to send that value..                            CString strFormData   _T("action=setCameraSetting&videoOverlay.useTimestamp=1&videoOverlay.useText=1&videoOverlay.displayString=12.12-77.32");

Comment: What's stopping you? You can pass the data to `SendRequest` via `lpOptional` and `dwOptionalLen` parameters. Or, you can initiate the request with `SendRequestEx` and follow with `CInternetFile::Write` or `WriteString`. Also, chances are high the server expects `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the kind of data you are sending, not `text/plain`

Comment: I got Exception : "The Connection with the server was reset" for     pFile->SendRequest(NULL, 0, (LPVOID)(LPCTSTR)strFormData, strFormData.GetLength());
and SendRequestEx function is not available and for WriteString or Write function getting error (In a small frame) "Debug Assertion failed", with options Abort, Retry and Ignore.

Comment: Well, the server didn't like the data you sent, and chose to drop the connection. Find out why. What do you mean by "SendRequestEx function is not available"? Who's taking it away from you?

Comment: SendRequestEx is not supported in Smart Device projects [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa43ek20(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I suggest you use a network sniffer, e.g. WireShark, to inspect the actual request you are sending to the server. If the request looks the way you expect, then debug the server. Otherwise, fix the client so that it sends the correct request. If you have a known good, working client, you can inspect the request it sends to the server, and figure out what you are doing differently; this may prove illuminating.